# Why can a templatized derived class access its base private members on gcc?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, gcc, private-members

I'm in the process of learning c++. Now i understand that a derived class cannot access its base class private members, but why a templatized one can ?

for instance something like this works fine:

```
class base {
     static int x;
};
template<typename T>
class derived: public base{
    T t;
public:
    void setx(int i) {x=i;}
    int getx(){return x;}
};
```

I'm using gcc 5.4 on linux.

Comment: "works fine" with what compiler and switches??

Comment: This would appear to be a compiler bug. Which version of which compiler are you using?

Comment: gcc 5.4 on linux

Comment: Can reproduce by switching compilers on @songyuanyao's demo. Wow, that's a nasty bug.

Comment: @Quentin It still works with [gcc HEAD 8.0.1](https://wandbox.org/permlink/mbdBAMnaWVsURObe). Wow.

Comment: Works for me on `GCC 4.7` Linux............ mut be a bug. If I fully qualify the name I get the correct compiler error.

Comment: yeah, i've been scratching my head for days now trying to understand why does it compile and works fine.

Comment: @songyuanyao Still compiles and works perfectly on [gcc HEAD 10.0.0](https://wandbox.org/permlink/NpYx055cucg4U0oQ) with `-Wall -Wextra -Werror -pedantic-errors`.  Sigh ...

Answer (score 12):

This is a known bug of GCC, which seems to fail in performing access checking correctly in templates. See [Bug 58740](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=58740).

Unfortunately it's still not fixed.

BTW: [Clang](https://wandbox.org/permlink/ZVYMSa5Rz4uRTk3h) fails to compile, as expected.

Comment: No, it does not have to be static, it also compiles for non-static ones

Comment: @s.clarck I checked it with [online compiler](https://wandbox.org/permlink/p9eMC00fIkPV4IdZ) and it fails as expected.

Comment: hmm, strange, on my  system, it does compile (without static)

Comment: @s.clarck Well, for either case, it should **not** compile.

Comment: Its ironic that the ClangCodeModel (within my IDE) flagged it as an error, while the whole gcc compiler passed it.

Comment: Why such an old and well known bug is reported as "unconfirmed" in bugzilla?