# C++ Inheritance of private static member variable in

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance, static-members

I was running into an issue with templates and accessing a static private member of a base class in the derived class.

It seems that I can illegally access a base class private member variable from a templated derived class.

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo {
public:

  Foo() {};
  ~Foo() {};

private:

  static int some_variable;

};

int Foo::some_variable;

template<typename T>
class Bar : Foo {
public:

  Bar(T bla) {
    some_variable = bla;
  };
  ~Bar() {};

  void test() {
    std::cout << some_variable << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Foo A;

  Bar<int> B(2);
  B.test();
}
```

I would expect this code to not compile as the derived class tries to access a private variable in the parent class.
However it compiles without errors or warnings using gcc (`g++ -std=c++11 -O3 test.cpp -Wall -Wextra`) but with clang (`clang -x c++ test.cpp`) it throws an error about the variable being a private member

Removing "some_variable" non static results in an error with g++, and making "Bar" a non templated class also results in an error from g++.
What am I missing here?

My g++ version is (Ubuntu 5.4.0-6ubuntu1~16.04.11) 5.4.0 20160609

Comment: In older version of the GCC the access specifer for template classes are broken. It may work or not. (they even made a cumulative bug report on it...). It has become better with GCC 9.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why can a templatized derived class access its base private members on gcc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49676271/why-can-a-templatized-derived-class-access-its-base-private-members-on-gcc)